# Angular 2 material design, setting minimal rows for autosize textarea

Tags: angular, textarea, angular-material2

Does anybody know how to set minimal rows for autosize Angular 2 material design `textarea` input element?

Here's my sample:

```
<md-input-container class="input-field message">
    <textarea md-input md-autosize minRows="3" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
</md-input-container>
```

Here's source codes:
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/input/autosize.ts

I noticed that it has input variable `minRows` and setting `[minRows]="3"` still didn't help.

I kinda stuck, please help.

**update:** I've tried to repeat this issue on plunkr and haven't succeeded. Seems my local CSS overrides somehow Angular material style.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem today and this works for me

```
<md-input-container class="full-width">
    <textarea mdInput mdTextareaAutosize minRows="6" placeholder="Beschrijving" id="description" formControlName="description"></textarea>
</md-input-container>
```

the textarea starts with 6 rows and expands if needed.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is `md-autosize` helps!

Comment: With the newest versions of Angular Material `md-input` and `md-autosize` will not work. Use: `mdInput` and `mdAutosizeMinRows`

Comment: Just run into the same issue. Thanks @HristoEftimov for the hint!

Comment: As of Angular Material 2.0.0b12, "md" prefixes have changed to "mat". So, the attribute for auto-sizing is now "matTextareaAutosize".

Comment: It is `cdkTextareaAutosize` now as `matTextareaAutosize` is about to be deprecated: https://material.angular.io/components/input/api#MatTextareaAutosize